Tomcat 10.1.6-1 Service annotation not working
I have been in the process of upgrading an Apache Tomcat 9.0.83 application to 10.1.6-1.
I have sorted out most of the Jakarta namespace changes but noticed that Beans injected with the @Service annotation are not available.
Our application is old, so the majority of classes are registered via XML and work. However the handful that use annotations are not available.
Resources using @AutoWire are null and trying to explicitly get the bean via aplicationContext.getBean("Foo") gives the following error.

[ERROR] [Mon Apr 08 11:10:35.258 2024] [ajp-nio-127.0.0.1-8009-exec-2|BackupServiceImpl] Error: checking if chosen file name Backup-20244811:10 already exists for the host 127.0.0.1
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'FOO' available
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:893) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1318) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1155) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at com.myCompany.AppContextUtil.getFoo(AppContextUtil.java:48) ~[myCompany-services-impl.jar:?]


Other annotations such as as PostConstruct work.
Foo.class:
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service; 
 
@Service("Foo") 
public class FooImpl extends FooIAbstract {

    public FooImpl() { 

    }    

} 


As per the top answer to this  question, checking for duplicate instances of jakarta.annotation.Resource, I did find the following two jars containing the jakarta.annotation.Resource class and excluded he jakarta.annotation-api-2.0.0.jar without any luck.
~/eclipse-workspace09/DEVELOP_5_1_8_8_BRANCH/base/dist/usr/local/tomcat (DEVELOP_5_1_8_8_BRANCH) 

$ find ./ -type f -iname '*.jar' | xargs grep --text --ignore-case --files-with-matches '.*jakarta.annotation.Resource.*' 
./lib/jakarta.annotation-api-2.0.0.jar 
./lib/tomcat-annotations-api-10.1.6.jar 

There was not any ComponentScan annotation in our prior code so I tried adding one without any effect.
@ComponentScan("com.Company")
public class AppContextListener implements ServletContextListener, HttpSessionListener  {


If I add an xml definition to our existing applicationContent.xml there are no errors trying to pull the bean by name from the context.

<bean id="Foo" class="com.Company.FooImpl"  lazy-init="true">
</bean>


Relevant dependencies from main pom.xml:
<org.springframework.version>6.0.11</org.springframework.version> 

 
<dependencies> 
    <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId> 
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version> 
        <scope>runtime</scope> 
    </dependency> 


    <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId> 
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version> 
        <scope>runtime</scope> 
    </dependency> 
     
    <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId> 
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version> 
    </dependency> 
 
    <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId> 
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version> 
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion> 
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId> 
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId> 
            </exclusion> 
        </exclusions> 
    </dependency> 
     
    <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId> 
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version> 
    </dependency> 

    <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId> 
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version> 
    </dependency> 


    <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId> 
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version> 
    </dependency> 

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
        <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId> 
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version> 
    </dependency> 

    <!--  

    <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId> 
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version> 
    </dependency> 

    <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
        <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId> 
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version> 
    </dependency> 
    
    <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
        <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId> 
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version> 
    </dependency> 

    <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId> 
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version> 
    </dependency> 

    <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId> 
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version> 
    </dependency> 

    <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId> 
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId> 
        <version>6.2.3</version> 
    </dependency> 

    <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId> 
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version> 
        <scope>test</scope> 
    </dependency> 

    <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId> 
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version> 
    </dependency> 

    <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId> 
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version> 
    </dependency> 

    <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId> 
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version> 
    </dependency> 
    
    <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
        <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId> 
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version> 
    </dependency> 
    
</dependencies> 


Your bean is named Foo not foo. That being said you cannot just upgrade Tomcat, you would also need to upgrade Spring to the 6.x range else it won't work. Other versions aren't compatible with Tomcat 10 (or rather JakartaEE).

@M.Deinum Yes, we have already upgraded to Spring 6.x ( and may other thing including hibernate).  This is one of the last issues we are facing.

The error probably has something to do with your configuration, as I already stated your bean is named Foo and not foo not sure if that is a copy/paste or something else. Removing jars is not the solution the solution is to fix your configuration. Please add the full stacktrace and the configuration that  has the component scanning etc. Also please add your dependencies (the maven file or gradle one).

@M.Deinum Sorry, 'foo' was a typo in trying to sanitize information.   Thank you for your input and suggested edits.

The @ComponentScan is on the wrong place it should be on an @Configuration class. You also state you use XML so you should have a <context:component-scan /> in there.

As M Deinum noted in the comments above, adding @Configuratio resolved this issue.
@Configuratio
@ComponentScan("com.Company")
public class AppContextListener implements ServletContextListener, HttpSessionListener  {

However adding <context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany"/> broke my application.
I am not at all certain how this worked in Tomcat 9.
Further reading for anyone that finds this in the future.
